# Select an option from a dropdown by its value - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, html-select, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-options

I have a factory which pulls dropdown options from a database:

```
app.factory('populateDDL', function($http) {
    'use strict';
    return function (tbl,key) {
        var json,
            data = JSON.stringify({
                sKey: key,
                sTableName: tbl
            });
        return $http.post('util.asmx/populateDDL',data).
        then(function(response) {
            return JSON.parse(response.data.d);
        });
    };
});
```

I then apply that data to a drop down list/select in my controller:

```
app.controller('userSettings', function($scope, $http, populateDDL) {
            $scope.clinicLocations = new populateDDL('locations',key).
            then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $scope.clinicsDDL = response.locations;
                $http({
                    url: 'util.asmx/returnUser', 
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {sUserId: uid},  
                })
                .success(function(user) {
                    $scope.user = user.d;
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data+', '+status+', '+headers+', '+config);
                });
            });
        });
```

Here is how the select tag looks:

```
<select ng-model="clinicsDDL.item" ng-options="item.name for item in clinicsDDL track by item.id" ngRequired />
```

The drop down list data which is put into $scope.clinicsDDL looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": "19",
    "name": "other clinic"
}, {
    "id": "39",
    "name": "My clinic"
}]
```

The returned user data from the DB looks like this:

```
{
    "__type": "User",
    "FirstName": "Erik",
    "LastName": "Grosskurth",
    "DefaultLocationId": "39"
}
```

Inside my controller I populate the drop down list/select and then I take a user ID and submit it to the DB for user information. This user information comes back. From then I want to select a specific option from the previously populated list based on what the "DefaultLocationId" is that is returned from the DB.

How would I go about doing this?

```
$scope.clinicsDDL.item = $scope.clinicsDDL[0];
```

^^^ doesn't work because I cannot depend on the array to always be formed the same. I need to target the array item based on "DefaultLocationId" and not an integer.

In jQuery you would target the selector by using $('#clinicsDDL option[value="19"').doSomething();

I was thinking it would be like that in angular something like this:

```
$scope.clinicsDDL.item = $scope.clinicsDDL[value="19"];
```

^^^ but that doesn't work either

Answer (score -1):

The pre-selection uses references only. When you want to select an element and you do not know which field contains it, then you have to search it. Instead of using array.filter() you should use lodash's find function (https://lodash.com/docs#find)

```
//preselect DefaultLocationId 39
$scope.clinicsDDL.item = _.find($scope.clinicsDDL, {DefaultLocationId : 39});
```

_.find(...) will return undefined when no item could be found. So you could leave it undefined or use a default value like

```
$scope.clinicsDDL.item = _.find($scope.clinicsDDL, {DefaultLocationId : 39}) || $scope.clinicsDDL[0];
```

Comment: angular.js:13424 ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Comment: You have to include lodash to your project and your html. See [lodash.com](https://lodash.com/).

Comment: That is not the Angular solution. I can also complete a one line fix in other plugins as well. I am looking for a pure Angular solution, Thank you

Comment: Then you could use array.filter() This approach is pure javascript. With the disadvantage that the function call will iterate over all elements of the array and returns an new array. When you don't want to use pure Javascript and force an AngularJS solution you could use the filter filter. Inject the $filter service into your controller and call `$filter("filter")($scope.clinicsDDL, {DefaultLocationId : 39})` Here the same disadvantage, you iterate over all elements in the array. Don't forget that tis returns an array. When the id is unique you musst access the return value at index 0